# PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, php-7.2

I'm getting the following error "PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered on line 11". The following code is for a pagination. I have tried everything I know, not sure what else to do. Any help is appreciated.

```
8 $rowsPerPage = 20;
9 if(isset($_GET['page'])){$pageNum = $_GET['page'];}
10 if(empty($pageNum)) {$pageNum = 1;}
11 $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
```

Comment: `$_GET['page']` is probably a string, cast it... or possibly a better approach: `$pageNum = (int)!empty($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;`

Comment: A `Warning` is not an `Error`...

Comment: `$pageNum` could be a string in line 11

Comment: PHP does not generate warnings when performing math operations on variables containing numerical strings, so `$_GET['page']` must contain something non-numbery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is not numeric (as obvious as that sounds, it is the error) and given you manually set all things to integer other than the GET value, try this:

```
$rowsPerPage = 20;
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $pageNum = (int) $_GET['page'];
}
if(empty($pageNum)) {
    $pageNum = 1;
}
$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
```

Notice the cast to `int` for the GET param.

You could also just cast to int and PHP will default to integer 0 if it's not already int:

```
$pageNum = (int) $_GET['page'];
```

---

Couldn't help myself - you can also use a ternary to make your setting of the `$pageNum` cleaner (IMO):

```
$rowsPerPage = 20;

$pageNum = isset($_GET['page'])
    ? (int) $_GET['page']
    : 1;

$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `$pageNum` is non-numeric, i.e. string, try:

```
$offset = (intval($pageNum) - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
```

Comment: If `$pageNum` is non-numeric, `intval` will convert it to zero. Subtracting 1 from 0 will give -1, and multiplying `$rowsPerPage` by -1 will give you a negative offset, probably not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

If `$_GET['page']` is non-numeric *don't just convert it to an int to get rid of the warning.* If it's non-numeric, converting it to a number will prevent the warning, but because non-numeric values will always be converted to zero, your pagination will never work.

If you want your pagination to work properly, you need to handle the warning by discovering *why* `$_GET['page']` is non-numeric and fixing that. Use a debugger or `var_dump($_GET['page']` to see what's actually in it. After you find that, you should be able to trace it back to whatever is making the request and correct the error there.